# Why won't false become true?

Tags: javascript, syntax, boolean, conditional-statements

I am working on a game, and for some reason these click functions are not permanently changing the top values to true, I use console log to test it, and the bottom log always says false. I know this might be simple but can anyone let me know?

```
var twoThree = false;
var fourFive = false;
var sevenEight = false;

// button click functions
$('#2_3').click(function(){
  twoThree = true;
  $('#start').hide();
  $('#game').fadeIn('slow');
});
$('#4_5').click(function(){
  var fourFive = true;
  $('#start').hide();
  $('#game').fadeIn('slow');
});
$('#7_8').click(function(){
  var sevenEight = true;
  $('#start').hide();
  $('#game').fadeIn('slow');
});
console.log(twoThree);
```

Comment: Why you declaring var `fourFive` and `sevenEight` again with `var` once they're declared globally? Just initialize it in the handler

Comment: Dirk, would you say that this question is answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `var` inside of the functions creates a new variable inside that scope, so the value in the outer scope is not changed.

Comment: the twoThree variable does not use var, and that is what I am testing, still shows as false.

Comment: the console log in your example is run before the click event. Try moving it into the click event after the actions have taken place. The thing to remember here is that JS is an async language, so it doesn't always run in order.

Comment: why? is that just the natural order of code to do that?

Comment: edited my previous comment to include the answer. The click functions are not fired until the DOM items are clicked.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have to quibble with your statement that "JS is an async language."  JavaScript is not asynchronous in any way.  There are certain JavaScript libraries and web browser integrations which are asynchronous, but the language itself is not.  JavaScript has many uses other than client-side web programming.

Comment: Hey Dan, Thanks, I agree, what I should have said was that things in the browser implementation of JS can be async, such as XHR and DOM events.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning the varibles using the keyword var. This is declaring a new variable on the scope of the function and set it to true.
The way to set the variables on the clausure of the functions must be through the window variable o just using the name of the variable.

This two calls will work.

```
window.fourFive = true;
fourFive = true;
```

This not.

```
var fourFive = true; // Is a local variable of the function
```